# MySQL2 error with RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is the error message:

```
/Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/JasonJiang/RubymineProjects/untitled6/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.rc/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/RubymineProjects/untitled6/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /Users/JasonJiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/JasonJiang/RubymineProjects/untitled6/script/rails:6:in `require'
from /Users/JasonJiang/RubymineProjects/untitled6/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks all!

Comment: do you have libmysqlclient installed ?

Comment: YES,it's already installed.
in my mysql/lib folder, I can find libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: I think this SA post has a better solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596303/rubymine-3-2-failing-to-find-libmysqlclient-18-dylib-on-macos-lion

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by opening up my project in the terminal using the /usr/local/bin/mine command. e.g.

```
mine .
```

For some reason, RubyMine isn't using the same environment one uses when just running 'rake test' from the command line (even though it uses the right .rvm version).

Comment: Thanks. And this problem is still not solved in Rubymine 4.5.

Comment: I still see it in Ruby 6, despite adding an explicit environment variable for DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (which works from the shell nicely)